# how to overwrite a JS file in magento?

Tags: javascript, overrides

I want to replace this JS.

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\web\js\price-options.js
```

I did try override by

```
\app\design\frontend\(vendor)\(theme)\Magento_Catalog\view\base\web\js\price-options.js
```

But seems not right...please help

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason to replace this js?

Better option to override is to use mixin:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `price-options.js` file form base template and put it in `app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-options.js`

And more information :-

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html**

Hope this help you

Thanks...

Comment: Hello @Paul Fan it's help or not???